# tkinter: Pass Initialization Parameters to A Subclassed Custom Widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyword-argument

I've been trying to create a custom widget in tkinter, nothing too fancy, just a frame that holds an entry and two labels. I want the labels and the frame to be able to access StringVars of the parent application (ie. the textvariables for both of the labels, and the entry textvariable as well). I thought this should be fairly straightforward to do by passing these names through the initialization method as keyword args, but I'm running into trouble. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class EntryFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title = kwargs.get('title')
        title = tk.Label(self, text=self.title)
        unit = tk.Label(self, text='(Unit)')
        self.entryVar = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVar)

        title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='es')
        unit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ws')
        entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3, sticky='n')

class TestApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master=master
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

        entryFrame  = EntryFrame(self, title='Title')
        entryFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
Application = TestApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm running into a problem where I can't actually pass anything else to my new widget, because it initializes with tk.Frame it seems to *only* want tk.frame attributes upon init. I can't actually give it args or kwargs.

If I try a different approach:

```
class EntryBox(self):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.title = tk.Label(self, text='Title')
        self.unit = tk.Label(self, text='(Unit)')
        self.entryVar = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.EntryVar)

        title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='es')
        unit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='es')
        entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3, sticky='n')
```

The class throws errors about self not being defined.

EDIT:

A better example of code sample 2:

```
class EntryBox():
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        self.title=kwargs.pop('title')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.title = tk.Label(self.frame, text=self.title)
        self.unit = tk.Label(self.frame, text='(Unit)')
        self.entryVar = tk.StringVar()


        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)

        self.title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='es')
        self.unit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='es')
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3, sticky='n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title, **kwargs):        
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
    self.title = title
```

In other words, avoid passing on your custom parameters to the superclass.

Or you could do `self.title = kwargs.pop('title')` BEFORE calling the superclass's `__init__`.

Your second code sample is simply confused - in `class EntryBox(self):`, what were you expecting 'self' to be?

Comment: Yeah, that second example was way off after looking at it again. I've made adjustments and posted a better version above. Is there anything wrong with not inheriting the new class from tk.Frame?

Comment: Subclassing a widget would be more convenient in general - you could directly add children to it, or configure options like the background color, without having to dig into the instance variables to get the actual widgets.  However, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your second approach.